# How to GROUP BY boolean when im already grouping by time frames 8hr/11hr/14hr/17hr/20hr in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery

I need to group 2 tables (Key = analysis_id <=> id) where my output should show the last *week or month or year*, grouped by a Time frame and grouped by **bolean "R" or "L"**. I have around 4000 inputs by users.

> Example of tables i have

```
 +----------+-------------+-------------+    +------+---------+------------------------+
 |                 t1                   |    |                 t2                      |
 +----------+-------------+-------------+    +------+---------+------------------------+
 | user_id  | Analyze_id  | result      |    |  id  | boolean |  date                  |
 +----------+-------------+-------------+    +------+---------+------------------------+
 | 1588     | 9001        | 0.753478    |    | 9001 | "R"     | 2022-10-30 06:38:29    |
 | 1588     | 9000        | 0.758452    |    | 9000 | "L"     | 2022-10-30 06:39:30    |

 | 1588     | 8554        | 0.853724    |    | 8554 | "R"     | 2022-10-22 11:48:42    |
 | 1588     | 8553        | 0.603724    |    | 8553 | "L"     | 2022-10-22 11:47:35    |
 
 | 1588     | 9887        | 0.931123    |    | 9887 | "R"     | 2022-10-01 14:48:40    |
 | 1588     | 9886        | 0.756321    |    | 9886 | "L"     | 2022-10-01 14:01:57    |

 | 1588     | 4832        | 0.755645    |    | 4832 | "R"     | 2022-10-01 17:18:14    |
 | 1588     | 4831        | 0.987445    |    | 4831 | "L"     | 2022-10-01 17:17:24    |

 | 1588     | 2458        | 0.662494    |    | 2458 | "R"     | 2022-10-01 21:18:12    |
 | 1588     | 2458        | 0.864524    |    | 2458 | "L"     | 2022-10-01 21:17:12    |
 +----------+-------------+-------------+    +------+---------+------------------------+
```

> Time Range:

- 8h includes 6h to 9h29
- 11h includes 9h30 to 12h29
- 14h includes 12h30 to 15h29
- 17h includes 15h30 to 18h29
- 20h includes 18h30 to 23h59

For the moment i reach to handle the join + the time frames and the average by group. The problem is that my code is grouping by time-frame without taking care of the **boolean "R" or "L"** so the output of results is mixing "R" and "L" all in one group adding and doing the average and i need to be separated

```
SELECT 
    max(t1.user_id) AS user_id,     
    max(t2.boolean) AS boolean, 
    AVG(t1.`result`* 8) AS result, 
    max(t2.`date`) max_date,
    case 
        when  TIME(`date`) between '06:00:00' and '09:29:00' then '08h'
        when  TIME(`date`) between '09:30:00' and '12:29:00' then '11h'
        when  TIME(`date`) between '12:30:00' and '15:29:00' then '14h'
        when  TIME(`date`) between '15:30:00' and '18:29:00' then '17h'
        when  TIME(`date`) between '18:30:00' and '23:59:00' then '20h'
    end as 'time_intervals'
FROM table1_features t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.analysis_id = t2.id 
WHERE  `date` >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 1 month AND t1.user_id = 1588
GROUP BY time_intervals
ORDER BY max_date ASC
```

### Actual output :

```
 +----------+-------------+------------------------------+   
 |           Actual output                               |   
 +----------+-------------+------------------------------+   
 | user_id  |   result    |   boolean   | time_intervals |
 +----------+-------------+------------------------------+   
 | 1588     |  0.753478   |      R      |       08h      |  
 | 1588     |  0.603724   |      R      |       14h      |
 | 1588     |  0.931123   |      R      |       11h      |
 | 1588     |  0.755645   |      R      |       17h      |
 | 1588     |  0.662494   |      R      |       20h      |
 +----------+-------------+------------------------------+
```

### Expected output:

```
 +----------+-------------+------------------------------+   
 |           Actual output                               |   
 +----------+-------------+------------------------------+   
 | user_id  |   result    |   boolean   | time_intervals |
 +----------+-------------+------------------------------+   
 | 1588     |  0.753478   |      R      |       08h      |
 | 1588     |  0.753478   |      L      |       08h      |
 | 1588     |  0.603724   |      R      |       14h      |
 | 1588     |  0.603724   |      L      |       14h      |
 | 1588     |  0.931123   |      R      |       11h      |
 | 1588     |  0.931123   |      L      |       11h      |
 | 1588     |  0.755645   |      R      |       17h      |
 | 1588     |  0.755645   |      L      |       17h      |
 | 1588     |  0.662494   |      R      |       20h      |
 | 1588     |  0.662494   |      L      |       20h      |
 +----------+-------------+------------------------------+
```

> Or something similar where i have the AVR result per time-frame and by Bolean.

Comment: Change `max(t2.boolean) AS boolean,` with `t2.boolean` and add it in the group by clause. `GROUP BY time_intervals,t2.boolean`

Comment: i will try that. thanks

Comment: Oh my god is working !! i have been 1week with these query thanks a lot.. woud you like to make an answer and i put it as an accepted answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already suggested in the comments you need to change

`max(t2.boolean) AS boolean` with `t2.boolean` and add `t2.boolean` in the group by clause `GROUP BY time_intervals,t2.boolean`.

The final query would look like:

```
SELECT 
    max(t1.user_id) AS user_id,     
    t2.boolean, 
    AVG(t1.`result`* 8) AS result, 
    max(t2.`date`) max_date,
    case 
        when  TIME(`date`) between '06:00:00' and '09:29:00' then '08h'
        when  TIME(`date`) between '09:30:00' and '12:29:00' then '11h'
        when  TIME(`date`) between '12:30:00' and '15:29:00' then '14h'
        when  TIME(`date`) between '15:30:00' and '18:29:00' then '17h'
        when  TIME(`date`) between '18:30:00' and '23:59:00' then '20h'
    end as 'time_intervals'
FROM table1_features t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.analysis_id = t2.id 
WHERE  `date` >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 1 month AND t1.user_id = 1588
GROUP BY time_intervals,t2.boolean
ORDER BY max_date ASC
```